# Implementing a tally with python logger module

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to create a python logger handler that handles tallies nicely.  For example, I might logging.debug something a thousand times a second.  After, say, 10 seconds, I want to logging.info the fact that that thing happened 10,000 times in those 10 seconds.  I have something set up to do it, but it seems kind of icky, and I was wondering if any python logging gurus could help out.  Ideally, I would like to have my tally handler periodically pass a tally record to the standard handler...

Here's what I have so far:

```
class CounterHandler(logging.Handler):
  '''
  This handler is to log only counts of messages.  
  So, for instance, suppose we want to logging.debug event A 
  which happens about once a millisecond, but we may want to 
  logging.info every second how many times event A happened 
  during that second.
  '''
  def __init__(self, pattern, message, logger, howoften = 1, timer = time.time, leastlevel = logging.NOTSET, messagelevel = logging.INFO, plot = False):
    '''
    pattern: the regex pattern in log messages to count
    leastlevel: the least logging level to count
    handler: the handler to hand accumulated counts to
    message: the message to log when we log accumulated counts
    messagelevel: the logging level at which to log accumulated counts
    howoften: how often to log accumulated counts
    timer: the timer to use (default is real time, but you can use, e.g. simpy time or something else)
    '''
    logging.Handler.__init__(self)
    self._regex = re.compile(pattern)
    self._msg = message
    self._messagelevel = messagelevel
    self._leastlevel = level
    self._logger = logger
    self._count = 0
    self._howoften = howoften
    self._timer = timer

    self.stopper = threading.Event()
    self._propogation_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._propogate, args=(self.stopper, timer))
    self._propogation_thread.daemon = True
    self._propogation_thread.start()

  def _dump(self):
    self._logger.log(self._messagelevel, 
                     "{} happened {} times by time {}".format(self._msg, 
                                                              self._count, 
                                                              self._timer()))


  def _propogate(self, stopper, timer):
    '''
    This is a thread that dumps the counts every so often 
    '''
    lasttime = timer()
    while not stopper.is_set():
      if lasttime + self._howoften < timer():
        self._dump()

  def emit(self, record):
    if record.level >= self._level and regex.match(record.message):
      self._count += 1
```

EDIT:
@Reut, The other side of this problem is actually complicated.  The reason I want to hand it to another handler is because I want to have flexibility in what I do with the counts that I get.  I have a module that graphs counts in real time, but I also have a log file that it would be nice to output to.  In which case, it seems that I should be doing something along the lines of chaining handlers, then I can add or subtract functionality as I see fit.  Viz:

```
The big picture:
                                               ,-> LogFileHandler    
My Code -> Log Message -> Logger -> LogRecord <                    ,-> GrapherHandler
                                               `-> CounterHandler <
                                                                   `-> LogFileHandler
```

Comment: Can you show the other side of the problem? That is, the code you're using this in, with expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion easier is write handler which send `log.info` after `log.debug` happens for example 1000 times. In logs you have datetime so you can calculate average amount of `log.debug` per seconds, minutes, hours, etc.

To write this handler you can base on https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler